# Correct way to set up this Laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-6

I'm after a bit of logic advice. I am creating a system where users login and register their participation at an activity. They can participate at an activity many times. What is the best way to do this? I want to ensure I can use eloquent with this rather than creating my own functions.

I am imagining...

Users:

```
id
```

Activitys:

```
id
name
```

Participations:

```
id
user_id
activity_id
time_at_activity
```

I want to later be able to do such things as: 
`$user->participations->where('activity_id', 3)` 
for example.

What is the best way to set this up? I had in mind..

User: hasMany->Participations

Activity: belongsTo->Participation

Participation: hasMany->Activitys    &   belongsTo->User

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]The users schema can relate to activities through a pivot table called participations:

```
/**
 * Indicate that the model belongs to a user.
 *
 * @see \App\Model\User
 *
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the model belongs to many activity participations.
 *
 * @see \App\Model\Activity
 *
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function participations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class, 'participations');
}

$user->participations()->attach($activity);
```

You may want to add the reciprocal relationships. These can be separated out into traits for code reuse. `->attach(['participated_at' => now()])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) Relationship.

Use `Participation` as your pivot table. Define relationships as

```
/* in User */
public function activity()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activitys','participation','user_id','activity_id')->as('participation')->withPivot('time_at_activity');
} 

/* in Activity */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users','participation','activity_id','user_id')->as('participation')->withPivot('time_at_activity');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**DB schema** 
[image]

```
// App\User
public function participations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Participation');
} 
// You may create App\Participation Model
// App\Participation 
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
} 

// Controller
$userParticipations = $user->participations->where('activity_id', 3);
// eager loading version
$userWithParticipations = $user->with(['participations' => function($q) { $q->where('activity_id', 3) }])->get();
```